# Add wordpress post id to div

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm trying to add the post's id with the following

```
<div class="project-tile"><?php the_ID(); ?>>
```

But its returning the following without the

```
<div class="project-tile" 73>
```

Any ideas welcome

Answer (score 1):

use this if you want to add id:

```
<div class="project-tile" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"></div>
```

result is:

```
<div class="project-tile" id="post-73"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code. If your intention was to display the ID in the div it should be rather:

```
<div class="project-tile"><?php the_ID(); ?></div>
```